# Javascript moving divs around doesn't work on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, resize

I am using this script to  move around some divs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
onresize=onload=function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $("#MainContent").insertAfter($("#ImageSlider"));
        $("#Menu").insertBefore($("#TopBanner"));
    } else {
        $("#MainContent").insertBefore($("#ImageSlider"));
        $("#Menu").insertBefore($("#Footer"));
    }
};
</script>
```

Which is working nicely except on an iPad. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "screen.width"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
onresize=onload=function() {
    if (screen.width < 768) {
        $("#MainContent").insertAfter($("#ImageSlider"));
        $("#Menu").insertBefore($("#TopBanner"));
    } else {
        $("#MainContent").insertBefore($("#ImageSlider"));
        $("#Menu").insertBefore($("#Footer"));
    }
};
</script>
```